# Canvas draw functions not working after screen locked and unlocked

Tags: android, canvas, onresume, onpause

I'm working on an augmented reality application in which I have a camera preview screen on which I draw some markers which moves with respect to device movement.

When I `lock and unlock` the device, the markers freezes and doesn't move further. I'm unable to find the reason why this happens.Is there any possible work around for this? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**My SurfaceView class:**

```
    public class CameraSurface extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
    {
    private static SurfaceHolder holder = null;
    public static Camera camera = null;
    Activity ctx;

    public CameraSurface(Activity context) {
        super(context);
        ctx=context;

        try {
            holder = getHolder();
            holder.addCallback(this);
            holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public CameraSurface(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    }

    public CameraSurface(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            if (camera != null) {
                try {
                    camera.stopPreview();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    camera.release();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                camera = null;
            }

            camera = Camera.open();
            setCamFocusMode();
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            try {
                if (camera != null) {
                    try {
                        camera.stopPreview();
                    } catch (Exception ex1) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        camera.release();
                    } catch (Exception ex2) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    camera = null;
                }
            } catch (Exception ex3) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            if (camera != null) {
                try {
                    camera.stopPreview();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    camera.release();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                camera = null;
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {        
        if (camera==null) 
            return;
        try {
            final Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
            try {
                List<Camera.Size> supportedSizes = null;
                // On older devices (<1.6) the following will fail
                // the camera will work nevertheless
                supportedSizes = CameraCompatibility.getSupportedPreviewSizes(parameters);

                // preview form factor
                float ff = (float) w / h;

                // holder for the best form factor and size
                float bff = 0;
                int bestw = 0;
                int besth = 0;
                Iterator<Camera.Size> itr = supportedSizes.iterator();

                // we look for the best preview size, it has to be the closest
                // to the
                // screen form factor, and be less wide than the screen itself                
                while (itr.hasNext()) {
                    Camera.Size element = itr.next();
                    // current form factor
                    float cff = (float) element.width / element.height;
                    // check if the current element is a candidate to replace
                    // the best match so far
                    // current form factor should be closer to the bff
                    // preview width should be less than screen width
                    // preview width should be more than current bestw
                    // this combination will ensure that the highest resolution
                    // will win
                    if ((ff - cff <= ff - bff) && (element.width <= w) && (element.width >= bestw)) {
                        bff = cff;
                        bestw = element.width;
                        besth = element.height;
                    }
                }
                // Some Samsung phones will end up with bestw and besth = 0
                // because their minimum preview size is bigger then the screen
                // size.
                // In this case, we use the default values: 480x320
                if ((bestw == 0) || (besth == 0)) {
                    bestw = 480;
                    besth = 320;
                }
                parameters.setPreviewSize(bestw, besth);                
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                parameters.setPreviewSize(480, 320);
            }
            ///
            android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();

            android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(0, info);

            int rotation = ctx.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                    .getRotation();

            int degrees = 0;
            switch (rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                degrees = 0;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                degrees = 90;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                degrees = 180;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                degrees = 270;
                break;
            }

            int result;
            if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
                result = (360 - result) % 360;
                // compensate the mirror
            } else {
                // back-facing
                result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
            }
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);

            camera.setParameters(parameters);
            camera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void setCamFocusMode(){ 

        if(null == camera) { 
            return; 
         } 

        /* Set Auto focus */  
        Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters(); 
        List<String>    focusModes = parameters.getSupportedFocusModes(); 
        if(focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE)){ 
            parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);    
        } else  
        if(focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO)){ 
            parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO); 
        }    

        camera.setParameters(parameters); 
    }
}
```

**AugmentedView.java:** // This class draws the markers on camera preview screen

```
    /**
 * This class extends the View class and is designed draw the zoom bar, radar
 * circle, and markers on the View.
 * 
 */
public class AugmentedView extends View {

    private static final String TAG = "AugmentedView";
    private static final AtomicBoolean drawing = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private static final Radar radar = new Radar();
    private static final float[] locationArray = new float[3];
    private static final List<Marker> cache = new ArrayList<Marker>();
    private static final Set<Marker> updated = new HashSet<Marker>();

    public AugmentedView(Context context) {

        super(context);
        Log.v(TAG, "portrait              = "+CameraPreviewFragment.ui_portrait);
        Log.v(TAG, "useCollisionDetection = "+CameraPreviewFragment.useCollisionDetection);
        Log.v(TAG, "useSmoothing          = "+CameraPreviewFragment.useDataSmoothing);
        Log.v(TAG, "showRadar             = "+CameraPreviewFragment.showRadar);
        Log.v(TAG, "showZoomBar           = "+CameraPreviewFragment.showZoomBar);    
        //radar = new Radar(context);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (canvas == null) return;

        if (drawing.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            //Log.v(TAG, "DIRTY flag found, re-populating the cache.");

            // Get all the markers
            List<Marker> collection = ARData.getMarkers();

            // Prune all the markers that are out of the radar's radius (speeds
            // up drawing and collision detection)
            cache.clear();
            for (Marker m : collection) {
                m.update(canvas, 0, 0);
                if (m.isOnRadar() && m.isInView()&& m.isMarkerToBeShown()) cache.add(m);
            }
            /*//Draw only 10 markers
            if(cache.size()>10)
                collection = cache.subList(0, 10);
            else*/
                collection = cache;
            if (CameraPreviewFragment.useCollisionDetection) 
                adjustForCollisions(canvas, collection);

            // Draw AR markers in reverse order since the last drawn should be
            // the closest
            ListIterator<Marker> iter = collection.listIterator(collection.size());

            while (iter.hasPrevious()) {
                Marker marker = iter.previous();
                marker.draw(canvas);
            }

            // Radar circle and radar markers
            if (CameraPreviewFragment.showRadar) 
                radar.draw(canvas);
            drawing.set(false);
        }
    }

    private static void adjustForCollisions(Canvas canvas, List<Marker> collection) {
        updated.clear();

        // Update the AR markers for collisions
        for (int i=0; i<collection.size(); i++) {
            Marker marker1 = collection.get(i);
            if (!marker1.isInView()) {
                updated.add(marker1);
                continue;
            }
            if (updated.contains(marker1))
                continue;

            int collisions = 1;
            for (int j=i+1; j<collection.size(); j++) {
//                Marker marker2 = collection.get(j);
                Marker marker2 = collection.get(j);
                if (!marker2.isInView()) {
                    updated.add(marker2);
                    continue;
                }
                if (updated.contains(marker2))
                    continue;

                float width = marker1.getWidth();
                float height = marker1.getHeight();
                float max = Math.max(width, height);

                if (marker1.isMarkerOnMarker(marker2)) {
                    marker2.getLocation().get(locationArray);
                    float y = locationArray[1];
                    float h = collisions * max;
                    locationArray[1] = y + h;
                    marker2.getLocation().set(locationArray);
                    marker2.update(canvas, 0, 0);
                    collisions++;
                    updated.add(marker2);
                }
            }
            updated.add(marker1);
        }


   }
  }
```

Comment: where is the onDraw() method & the canvas?

Comment: That involves lot of classes and code. Couldn't post all of them here. Is there any possible reason why the issue occurs?

Comment: I can't tell you without seeing the rest of your code. at least the class containing the onDraw() method

Comment: @Shayan_Aryan Please see updated question

Comment: I don't know why your code is not working. If your live preview image continues to work, then the surfaceview is probably OK. I would put debug messages in onDraw to discover if it is being called.

Comment: I found out the issue. It was with my sensor.As u said,surface view was ok. Thanks for your help @emrys57 :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I resolved the issue. It was with my `SensorManager`. The `SensorManager` was null when `onStart()` is executed.I initialized it inside the `onStart()` and resolved it.