# getActivity() returns null in AsyncTask when called from another class

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have an `AsyncTask` to perform a task.I call this from the same class where the `AsyncTask` is written and from another class.

I have this statement in the code snippet for fetching user's current location:

```
GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(getActivity());
```

When called from same class, `getActivity()` has value but when called from another class, `getActivity()` returns null.

I tried using passing the context through constructor also:

```
 Context mContext;
 AsyncDataUpdate(Context context){
             this.mContext = context;
              }
GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(mContext);
```

which isn't working either.
What might be the reason?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: where you call GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(mContext); ?

Comment: inside my `AsyncDataUpdate`

Comment: you need put it in contruction of `AsyncDataUpdate` or `onPreExecute()`. and why your contruction is private ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mContext` variable after calling of `AsyncDataUpdate` class constructor  as:

```
GPSTracker gp;
Context mContext;
private AsyncDataUpdate(Context context){
     this.mContext = context;
     this.gps = new GPSTracker(this.mContext);
}
```

Comment: Can u please help me with another issue?

Comment: @Jas: sure i will try post it as new question and share link with me.Thanks

Comment: Thanks.Please see this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33909257/canvas-draw-functions-not-working-after-screen-locked-and-unlocked

Comment: Could you please help me??